# MSI Installer for Cygwin Application

Tags: windows-installer, cygwin

I've been looking around the internet, and I can't find a solution to the following question:

I have authored a program in C using cygwin. It is actually a port of a linux app, and makes heavy use of cygwin's posix emulation. How can i package this program into an MSI? is there a way to do it without resorting to Microsoft Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An MSI package can be created in multiple ways:

- use a [Visual Studio setup project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Win_App_Setup_Project.aspx)
- use a free setup authoring tool like [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/)
- use a [commercial setup authoring tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software) which supports NAnt

For MSI packages it doesn't matter how the application was developed or what it uses. Just make sure that you include all your application dependencies and configure them correctly during install.